# Return list of available topics in rosjava?

Tags: ros, topic, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to make a Swing GUI where I can subscribe to different available topics at run-time. The idea would be that you could right click somewhere on the GUI, and a list of available topics would pop up. You could then select a topic and it would automatically create a widget that would subscribe to the said topic and display relevant information.

Is there a way to list all of the topics running on a core from within a rosjava program? Ideally, it would act in a manner similar to calling rostopic list, but allow the program running to read in the names of the topics. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

-Joe Amato

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12123/return-list-of-available-topics-in-rosjava?/) by [Joe](https://answers.ros.org/users/1318/joe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That isn't currently implemented in rosjava. See: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/node/client/MasterClient.java

If you'd like to be notified when support is added, please file an issue: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0